# Github action for `yarn build` fails with missing React component

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment

I have a React app that builds correctly locally with `yarn build`. I have the following job in my config for Github Actions to deploy the app to S3:

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-2

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: yarn install

    - name: Build
      run: yarn build

    - name: Deploy static site to S3 bucket
      run: aws s3 sync build/ s3://my-s3-bucket --delete
```

The Build phase is failing with this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Layout' in '/home/runner/work/storefront-app/storefront-app/src'
```

This module does exist under the `src/components/` directory, so I'm not sure why it can't be found. I'm exporting it with `export default Layout;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found that the issue was with filenames and Git.

Locally, all my files were named correctly: Nav.js, Layout.js, etc. On Github, they were downcased: layout.js. Git never picked up the change to the filename, and so the build on GH could not find `./components/Layout`. Deleting the files and re-committing them solved the problem.

Comment: How did you realize about this filenames casing ? i'm having some similar issues but i'm not sure if this is the problem

Comment: Same for me, I renamed Layout by Layouts, it worked then I renamed it back to Layout. Work fine!

Comment: Yep I had the same issue, somehow github did not rename the folder/file properly. I added the following step in github actions so it helps me to debug the issue:
    steps:
    - name: List directory
      run: ls -la ./src/components